# Meshes invisible

Tags: objects, 3d-view

No matter what I try (I've tried changing clipping and local view), it ends up like this. Even adding new meshes. This happens on 2.8, 2.81,.82,.83 etc. It doesn't happen on 2.9+ why is this happening?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a GPU from AMD?

Comment: Yes I am using an amd gpu